# How does c process series of +-?

Tags: c, operators

Can somebody explains how does c process series of +-? 
For instance:

```
int x = 5, y = 8;

printf("%d\n", x-+-y); /* out: 13 */
printf("%d\n", x-+-+y); /* out: 13 */
printf("%d\n", x-+-+-y); /* out: -3 */
printf("%d\n", x+-+y); /* out: -3 */
printf("%d\n", x+-+-y); /* out: 13 */
printf("%d\n", x+-+-+y); /* out: 13 */
```

P. S. I use std=c90 so answer for all standards if answer is different, please.

Comment: Do you know about unary plus and unary minus, i.e. that `+x` and `-x` are valid?

Comment: @Ry- I don't think it's the simple `x-` `+` `-y` that is the issue, it's the next one: `x-` `+-` `+y`. In addition to the unitary operators, there's still some `-+-` operations in the middle.

Comment: @daShier All of the operators after the first one are unary operators. It's not `x-` `+` `-y`, it's `x` `-` `+-y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## x-+-y

This is evaluated as `x-(+(-y))`.

## x-+-+y

This is evaluated as `x-(+(-(+y)))`.

## x-+-+-y

This is evaluated as `x-(+(-(+(-y))))`.

## x+-+y

This is evaluated as `x+(-(+y))`.

## x+-+-y

This is evaluated as `x+(-(+(-y)))`.

## x+-+-+y

This is evaluated as `x+(-(+(-(+y))))`.

---

In this case, there are no concurrent sequences of `+` or `-`, so all `+`s or `-`s after the initial `+` or `-` are unary operators.